# SSH to raspberry pi - no matching key exchange method found

Tags: ssh

I have set up a Raspberry Pi 4 with the current Raspberry Pi OS in my home network. When I try to connect to it via ssh I get:

```
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.xxx.xxx port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer:
 sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,
 curve25519-sha256,
 curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,
 ecdh-sha2-nistp256,
 ecdh-sha2-nistp384,
 ecdh-sha2-nistp521, 
 diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,
 diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,
 diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,
 diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
```

(inserted line breaks for readability)

So I inserted into my `.ssh/config` on my Macbook:

```
Host myraspberrypi
    HostName 192.168.xxx.xxx
    User me
    KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
```

Then the answer to `ssh myraspberrypi` was again:

```
Unable to negotiate with 2001:xxxx...xxxx port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
```

(Note the ipv6 address here!?)

How can I make my Macbook talk to the raspberry pi?

Comment: What's the output of `ssh -V`  and `ssh -Q kex` on your macbook? You may have outdated ssh on that...

Comment: `ssh -V`is `OpenSSH_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6`.

Comment: `ssh -Q kex`: ```diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
diffie-hellman-group16-sha512
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
curve25519-sha256
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com```

Comment: Curious. That's from your macbook? There's several overlapping KEX there...

Comment: Solved. It was my fault, there was another host specification in the `.ssh/config` that conflicted with the new raspberry pi. 
Sorry for the disturbance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your post is a red herring; MacOS & Pi have mostly identical kex.

WHY do people bother hiding private IP addresses?

Use proper addressing e.g `myraspberrypi.local`

Have you set public keys on the Pi?
What IP addresses are in use?
Why specify kex - let systems negotiate a common key exchange method?

My Mac .ssh/config in part (although you may disagree with some settings)

```
Host 10.1.*.*
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UseKeychain yes
   BatchMode yes
   PasswordAuthentication yes
   User xxx

Host Pi5
        Hostname …Pi5.local
```

Comment: You are totally right, it was a mistake on my side. I forgot that I had a raspberry pi with the same name in a different network. There was a host specification in my somewhat lengthy `.ssh/config` that conflicted with the new pi.